# How to get substring out of String in java?

Tags: java

i am getting this String input="One Two Three";
how to get substrings out of it?
I want to get optimized solutions.
help me!

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: So you didn't want to use `java.lang.String#substring` then?

Comment: There are 91 possible substrings of `input`. Which ones do you want?

Comment: @AndyTurner: Nice. You even included the string itself.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a [String Tokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) or, if you know where the substrings are, use `.substring(int start,int end)`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
String substrings[] = input.split(" ");
```

Comment: Assuming a space delimiter, which the OP has not specified.

Answer (score 1):

Use Split in java

```
String input="one two three";
String[] output=input.split(" ");
System.out.println(output[0]);
System.out.println(output[1]);
System.out.println(output[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will work for your scenario:

```
 String input = "One Two Three";
 String[] splitWords = input.split(" ");    

 for ( String word : splitWords){
       System.out.println(word);
  }
```